# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Arg_ParamName_Name

Tags: vb.net, forms

I'm trying to add Items to my item list then load images in the inventory but keep ending up with this error and I'm not sure why. I'm making a game which uses visual basic and forms.

```
Public Class InvInterface
Public ItemMax As Integer = 9 'Number of inventory slots
Public Items As New List(Of Items)



Public Sub Add(Newitem As Items)
    If Items.Count <= ItemMax Then
        For Each I As Items In Items
            If I.Name = Newitem.Name Then
                If I.IsStackable = True And I.ItemCount < 16 Then
                    I.ItemCount += 1
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    Items.Add(Newitem)
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Items.Add(Newitem)
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub Remove(ItemID As Items)
    If Items.Item(Items.IndexOf(ItemID)).ItemCount > 0 Then
        Items.Item(Items.IndexOf(ItemID)).ItemCount -= 1
    Else
        Items.RemoveAt(Items.IndexOf(ItemID))
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub UpdateInv()
    For i = 1 To ItemMax
        If 0 < Items.Count Then
            Select Case i

                Case 1
                    Inv11.Image = Items(i).ImageAsset
                Case 2
                    Inv12.Image = Items(i).ImageAsset
                Case 3
                    Inv13.Image = Items(i).ImageAsset
                Case 4
                    Inv21.Image = Items(i).ImageAsset
                Case 5
                    Inv22.Image = Items(i).ImageAsset
                Case 6
                    Inv23.Image = Items(i).ImageAsset
                Case 7
                    Inv31.Image = Items(i).ImageAsset
                Case 8
                    Inv32.Image = Items(i).ImageAsset
                Case 9
                    Inv33.Image = Items(i).ImageAsset

            End Select



        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Dim Cobblestone As New Items
Dim WoodPlank As New Items
Dim currancy As New Items
Dim Flower As New Items
Dim CactusPlant As New Items
Public Sub initialiseItems()

```
    With cobblestone
        .Item = ItemClass.Blocks
        .Name = "Stone"
        .Description = "Comes from the ground made from rock"
        .IsStackable = True
        .ImageAsset = My.Resources.Stone
    End With
    With WoodPlank
        .Item = ItemClass.Blocks
        .Name = "Wood"
        .Description = "Wood planks can be used to create structures"
        .IsStackable = True
        .ImageAsset = My.Resources.Wood
    End With
    With Flower
        .Item = ItemClass.Usable
        .Name = "Flowers"
        .Description = "Gives small health boost"
        .IsStackable = True
        .ImageAsset = My.Resources.HumanBrainIcon
    End With
    With currancy
        .Item = ItemClass.Specials
        .Name = "Gold Coin"
        .Description = "These can be used at a merchant shop or casino"
        .IsStackable = True
        .ImageAsset = My.Resources.Coin
    End With
    With CactusPlant
        .Item = ItemClass.Usable
        .Name = "Cactus"
        .Description = "Gives a substantial health boost"
        .IsStackable = True
        .ImageAsset = My.Resources.Florance
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: A `List` collection is `0` based. -- This is not VBA -- With `forms` you probably mean `winforms`, tag your question so it's more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Lists Indexes goes from 0 to Lenght -1 so in

```
Public Sub UpdateInv()
```

you need to change the for loop to:

```
For i = 0 To ItemMax -1
```

and in the selectCase

```
Select Case (i-1)
```

or each case to 0 based index (start in 0 and go to 8)

Comment: I've tried this but still end up with the same error when the lines are run, the error seems to be in the case during the items(i).ImageAsset